# When an app with in-app purchase is removed by Google from the Play store, what happens to users in regard to the apk?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, apk

My question is about when an app is removed by Google from the Play store for any infringement of the guidelines or other abuse, in the case that it featured in-app purchases,i.e. because it is "freemium".

I mean, the user still has the app installed on the device, but if the user uninstalls it, is the apk lost forever? Is the re-installation still possible for the ones that purchased?

Comment: No, reinstallation is *not* possible because the APK will be deleted from the Google Play servers. However, users are still able to use the app, just without any Google services usable (GCM, IAP etc.)